# How to query with time filters in GoogleScraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-search

Even if Google's official API does not offer time information in the query results - even no time filtering for keywords, there is time filtering option in the advanced search:

[Google results for stackoverflow in the last one hour](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=qdr%3Ah1%2Csbd%3A1&ei=7B7vW8HBEtHXwQLz8J3YCg&q=stackoverflow&oq=stackoverflow&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.4020584.4023238..4023319...2.0..0.135.2001.0j16......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i67.jTKZ6v2w0CI)

[GoogleScraper](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper/) library  offers many flexible options BUT time related ones. How to add time features using the library?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of inspection, I've found that time Google sends the filtering information by `qdr` value to the `tbs` key (possibly means `time based search` although not officially stated):

https://www.google.com/search?tbs=qdr:h1&q=stackoverflow

This gets the results for the past hour. `m` and `y` letters can be used for months and years respectively.

Also, to add sorting by date feature, add the `sbd` (should mean `sort by date`) value as well:
https://www.google.com/search?tbs=qdr:h1,sbd:1&q=stackoverflow

I was able to insert these keywords to the BASE Google URL of GoogleScraper. Insert below lines to the end of `get_base_search_url_by_search_engine()` method (just before `return`) in `scraping.py`:

```
if("google" in str(specific_base_url)):
    specific_base_url = "https://www.google.com/search?tbs=qdr:{},sbd:1".format(config.get("time_filter", ""))
```

Now use the `time_filter` option in your config:

```
from GoogleScraper import scrape_with_config

config = {
            'use_own_ip': True,
            'keyword_file': "keywords.txt",
            'search_engines': ['google'],
            'num_pages_for_keyword': 2,
            'scrape_method': 'http',
            "time_filter": "d15" #up to 15 days ago
        }

search = scrape_with_config(config)
```

Results will only include the time range. Additionally, text snippets in the results will have raw date information:

```
one_sample_result = search.serps[0].links[0]
print(one_sample_result.snippet)
```

> 4 mins ago It must be pretty easy - let propertytotalPriceOfOrder =
>   order.items.map(item => +item.unit * +item.quantity * +item.price);.
>   where order is your entire json object.